# check nullable value object in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I wanna check a string nullable value. But its not work? Plz, someone show me how?

```
<%= LDC.Helpers.DataHelper.GetLabel(LDC.Helpers.DataHelper.getTypeMaxGrossWU(), (int)item.MGW_unit) != null ? LDC.Helpers.DataHelper.GetLabel(LDC.Helpers.DataHelper.getTypeMaxGrossWU(), (int)item.MGW_unit): "" %>
```

Comment: your exemple it's not razor but web form engine

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `GetLabel` returns `null` your code should work, so it appears it does not return `null`. Check the function's return type to see what equality check you should use.

Also, it's worth saying that this kind of logic should be put into a ViewModel. Putting it into your view is dangerously close to having spaghetti code.

Comment: Thanks, i think coz the 'spaghetti code' :D , i've changed it to ==null but it's not work too, then i check it in database. Anyway, thanks!